# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am getting this error only when trying to print `id` of the first question of the `questions` array. (I am getting value, also this error showing in console )

```
<p> {{ questions[0].id }} </p>
```

But when I trying to loop questions,there is no error.

```
<p v-for="i in questions" :key="i.id">
   {{ i.id }}
</p>
```

#### Script section of the template

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      questions: []
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get('/get_questions')
      .then((res) => {
        this.questions = res.data
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when the page has just loaded, the `questions` is an empty array.

When you trying to loop an empty array, the loop body just simply doesn't run:

```js
for(let i of []) {
  // this part will not reach
}
```

But when you trying get a parameter from the first element(which is `undefined`) of an empty array, it will throw you an error.

```js
[][0].id  // can't read ".id" from undefined
```

What you can do is to make sure `questions` has contents in it:

```
<p v-if="questions.length > 0"> {{ questions[0].id }} </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This throws because your accessing index [0] at your interpolation firsthand even before the axios complete the requires hence throwing an error.

This is not safe and will definitely cause an errors.
what you can do was to do  was to add some conditions at your interpolation

```
{{ questions.length > 0 ? questions[0].id: '' }}
```